# Logistic regression w/ categorical predictors, and all residuals must be nonnegative

Tags: r, regression, logistic, constrained-regression

Has anyone written a package for R that can do a logistic regression over categorical variables (like `glm`) but with the constraint, and I do realize this is weird, that *all the residuals must be nonnegative?*  (In response space, not link space.  In other words, the predicted probability in each cell must come out less than or equal to the observed probability in that cell.) Alternatively, is there a straightforward way to transform a `glm` problem so that it will come out with nonnegative residuals?

I know I can probably persuade `optim` to do what I want but if a shortcut exists that sure would be nice.

Comment: Without wanting to discourage you, it seems like you are asking for systematically biased estimates and those are hard to get purposely. I can't think of a way outside using a custom cost-function in conjunction with an optimization routine; Having said that this is not the end of the world: 1. You already have a good candidate solution with the solution from GLM; you just need to move the *intercept coefficient*: 2. GLM usually are solved through [IRLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) which is an optimization problem to begin with.

Comment: I can meet your requirement by setting the predicted probability to 0 for all X. But this probably isn't what you want. Please provide more information.

Comment: @HongOoi I was able to paper over the problem by subbing in a robust regression algorithm (`glmrob` from `robustbase`) but I really do just want to carry out the standard generalized linear regression procedure with the additional constraint that all residuals must be nonnegative. The larger context is "https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151568/efficiently-processing-a-large-mxnx2-logistic-regression-only-interactions-matt": the interaction is all I care about, but if I include an interaction term the model is overfit, and the interaction will be easier to analyze if it's nonnegative.